# Apache Mod Rewriting Rule Issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need small help with apache mod rewriting.
My URL is as below and I want to remove ?load=/ from my URL. What rewriting rule should I use?

```
http://xyz.abc/?load=/browse
```

Final URL should look like

```
http://xyz.abc/browse
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also you should consider rewriting the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} load=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1?
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=cb41b74e-3af1-5990-adf5-3f146aaf49b8